# Python 3 ; Rock Paper Scissors - Just Keeps Choosing One Outcome

Tags: python-3.x

Writing a little RPS game and I ran into a problem.

1) When I run the function to play the game, it always returns as a "Tie"
even if I choose a losing variable ex. cpu = rock, player = scissors

I'm kind of stumped on this. I usually lurk the stackoverflow forum when I'm having troubles, but I haven't encountered someone that has the same problem (even with the plethora of RPS questions on here).

Now, I'm not asking for anybody to write and test it 100% for me, but rather just show me the error spot and I'll go troubleshoot.

Thanks!

```
def showRules():
    print("********** Rock, Paper, Scissors **********")
    print("Rules: Each player chooses either Rock, Paper, or Scissors.")
    print("       The winner is determined by the following rules:")
    print("       Scissors cuts Paper -> Scissors wins")
    print("       Paper covers Rock   -> Paper Wins")
    print("       Rock smashes Scissors -> Rock Wins")
    print("*******************************************")

def getCPUChoice():
    choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    from random import randint
    randNum = randint(0,2)
    cpuchoice = choices[randNum]
    print(cpuchoice)
    return

def getUserChoice():
    choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    userchoice = input('Please choose either rock, paper or scissors:').lower()
    print(userchoice)
    return

def declareWinner(user, computer):
    if user == computer:
        print("Tie!!")
    elif user == "rock" and computer == "paper":
        print("You lose!")
    elif user == "paper" and computer == "scissors":
        print("You lose!")
    elif user == "scissors" and computer == "rock":
        print("You lose!")


def playGame():
    showRules()
    computer = getCPUChoice()
    user = getUserChoice()
    declareWinner(user, computer)
```

Comment: You return nothing in every case... therefore user = None, and so does computer = None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In getCPUChoice and getUserChoice, you are printing the choices instead of returning them. Change the returns at the end of those functions to

```
    return cpuchoice
```

and

```
    return userchoice
```

respectively.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. Now, just to make it more aesthetically appealing.